# How to suppress warnings for one ActionScript file?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, compiler-warnings, flashdevelop

I've got an ActionScript 3 source file (.as) that has hundreds of untyped variables. This file works perfectly although it outputs a warning for every untyped variable which gets me ~800 warnings clogging the Error panel in my IDE.

Although warnings are helpful in my other source files, I want to suppress warnings for this one .as file, because I'm in no mood to specify data types for them all.

Is this possible?

I'm using FlashDevelop 3 on Windows 7,
and compiling an AS3 AIR project using the Flex 4 SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a *real* solution but if you mark your untyped variable with type *, flash builder will not show warnings:

```
var example:* = event.result.something;
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to `Project` -> `properties` -> `Compiler Options` and set `Show Actionscript warnings` to false.

**PS**: Sorry, I've just noted that you were asking how to supress the warnings for *a particular file*, not the whole project. I don't think that's possible (unless you compile this file in a separate project, for instance, but that's probably overkill).